# Cannot build Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I followed [contribution-guide](https://beam.apache.org/contribute/contribution-guide/) for Apache Beam to setup my development environment. The project compiles fine, however I always get following failure when I run `mvn verify`:

> [ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time
>   elapsed: 60.315 s <<< FAILURE! - in
>   org.apache.beam.runners.apex.examples.WordCountTest [ERROR]
>   testWordCountExample(org.apache.beam.runners.apex.examples.WordCountTest)
>   Time elapsed: 32.259 s  <<< FAILURE! java.lang.AssertionError: result
>   files exist   at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)

When I run test `org.apache.beam.runners.apex.examples.WordCountTest`via IntelliJ, all assertions passes. I have a feeling there is a race condition in the assertion that is failing. Am I missing something to setup the environment?

Comment: It looks like the shard result files should be left in `runners/apex/target/wordcount.txt-*` in such a failure case. Do you see the files there?

Comment: @KennKnowles I see both output files in path `runners/apex/target` as `path/wordcountresult.txt-00000-of-00002` and `path/wordcountresult.txt-00001-of-00002` as configured in the test. As this passes fine when run via IntelliJ and assertion fails at the line checking the existence of files when main is invoked before the assertion. I suspect race condition.

Comment: @KennKnowles If I add `Thread.sleep()` before assertion, `mvn verify` passes no problem which proves my theory. You need to wait until file is available, otherwise this test is non-deterministic and should not be part of unit test.

Comment: Should I create an issue in Beam for this?

Comment: Yes, you should! Good catch.

Comment: Issue is created: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-3319